# A rhombus is constructed out of natural numbers with the length of the side being 1,2,3,... in a way specified below.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

A rhombus is constructed out of natural numbers with the length of the side being 1,2,3,... in a way specified below. 
Find the sum of the n'th rombs numbers and prove the correctness of the result with the way of mathematical induction.

### [image: rombs]

So there is no problem with finding the n'th rombs sum. It's n^3.
But I'm having trouble with writing the left side of the equasion to use the mathematical induction.

.... = n^3

.... = (n+1)^3

Comment: Consider the diagonals. For your size $4$ rhombus they would be $(1, 2, 3, 4)$, $(2, 3, 4, 5)$, etc. Can you use this pattern to make a single expression?

Comment: (What kind of monster would ask for this result to be proven using induction? Gauss is turning in his grave.)

Answer (score 1):

To use induction, note each "rhombus" is constructed from the previous one by adding a diagonal on the lower left & lower right sides, with the very bottom number repeated between them. In particular, going from $k$ to $k+1$, the diagonals being added go from $k + 1$ to $2k + 1$, with the $2k + 1$ only occurring once. For example, from the third to the fourth rhombii, you have the diagonals of $4$ to $7$ added to the previous rhombus.

To use this in your inductive step, first let

$$S(n) = n^3 \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

You can easily confirm this works for $n = 1$ since you have just $1$ and that's equal to $1^3$. Assume \eqref{eq1A} gives the sum for all $n \le k$ for some $k \ge 1$. For $n = k + 1$, the sum (using the sum of an arithmetic series of $a_1$ to $a_n$ is $\frac{n(a_1 + a_n)}{2}$) would be

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
S(k) + 2\sum_{i=k+1}^{2k}i + (2k + 1) & = k^3 + 2\left(\frac{k((k+1) + 2k)}{2}\right) + (2k + 1) \\
& = k^3 + k(3k + 1) + (2k + 1) \\
& = k^3 + (3k^2 + k) + (2k + 1) \\
& = k^3 + 3k^2 + 3k + 1 \\
& = (k + 1)^3 \\
& = S(k+1)
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

This shows \eqref{eq1A} also gives the sum for $n = k + 1$. Thus, by induction, \eqref{eq1A} gives the sum of the numbers of the $n$'th rhombus for all $n \ge 1$.